# VBA: return a field of a type from excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function which returns a Type:

```
Public Type Person_t
    Name As String
    Age As Integer
End Type
```

Function signature is as follows:

```
Public Function GetPerson(Name As String) as Person_t
     ...
     GetPerson = result
End Function
```

As you can see, the return type of this function is a Person_t.

What I want to do, is to call this function from an excell sheet, and more specifically, get the Name field of the Person_t. Something like this I'd expect:

=GetPerson("Fred").Name

But this is of course an error. What would be the correct way?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? It would be much much easier to create a table of people and their ages, and then simply do a vlookup on the table.  The table can even be in a hidden worksheet if preferred.

Comment: Well, the actual code is a REST query where data is retrieved from an external server. I just did not want to expose the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tigeravatar raises a good point. There might be an easier way than trying to use custom data types in a UDF. But, assuming that you have a good reason for doing things this way, you could write an access function like this:

```
Function GetPersonData(Name As String, field As String) As Variant
    Dim p As Person_t
    Dim s As String
    p = GetPerson(Name)
    s = LCase(Trim(field))
    Select Case s
        Case "name":
            GetPersonData = p.Name
        Case "age":
            GetPersonData = p.Age
        Case Else:
            GetPersonData = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End Select
End Function
```

A stub for testing purposes:

```
Public Function GetPerson(Name As String) As Person_t
    If Name = "Fred" Then
        GetPerson.Name = "Fred Flinstone"
        GetPerson.Age = 50
    Else
        GetPerson.Name = "John Doe"
        GetPerson.Age = 18
    End If
End Function
```

Can be used in a spreadsheet like thus:

[image]

Comment: `GetPerson` can be inlined into `GetPersonData`, so you could get by with just 1 function (which takes 2 arguments). You could also of course have two 1-variable functions such as `GetName` and `GetAge`

Comment: I mean you have to wrap the "type" functions within another. You can't just have "type".

Comment: Some sort of wrapping is needed if you want to be able to use them from the spreadsheet. It would be nice if there was some way to extend native Excel types (as opposed to VBA types) but I don't think its possible.

Comment: I need to research that before I understand it completely but thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!